# Error deserializing JSON that's been converted from XML first

Tags: .net, xml, json, serialization, json.net

I'm creating a .net app that manages some feeds from various web services. I've just started using JSON.NET and I'm looking to do all my conversion to my .net objects from JSON.

So, I thought for any feed that I can't get as JSON, I'd get the XML and convert it first to JSON, then I could use a single set of methods that process the JSON to do the actual work.

In doing this, I've encountered the following problem: after converting the XML to a JSON string (called `myInput`) with `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(myXMLdoc)`, I get an error when using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Object))(myInput)`:

> Cannot deserialize JSON object into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]'. Line 1, position
>   8.

`myInput` starts like this:

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8","@standalone":"yes"},"items":{"@size":"72","item":[{"id":"123456","description": ...
```

So, my question is *specifically* what is causing this error, but I'd be happy also to hear whether *generally* my approach is a good idea (i.e. converting all my input data to JSON before proceeding) - or if there's an established pattern for doing this sort of thing that I would be better learning about and implementing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is with wrong formatting of your JSON string.

Deserialization is complaining that you can't deserialize a JSON object into a List.

**{}**  - means JSON object = .NET object with properties on it or .NET dictionary

**[]**  - means JSON array = .NET array or list

So you should extract only items from the json string and store them as a '[]'

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm blindly using the json.net `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode` method here. It obviously can't anticipate what's an array vs. an object. Do you know what my alternatives might be?

Comment: Well maybe your xml needs some metadata on 'items' node that would tell JsonConvert that this is a list or array.